# What is the difference between a "normal" k-fold cross-validation using shuffle=True and a repeated k-fold cross-validation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, shuffle, k-fold

could anyone explain the difference between a "normal" k-fold cross-validation using the shuffle function, e.g.

```
kf = KFold(n_splits = 5, shuffle = True)
```

and a repeated k-fold cross-validation? Shouldn't they return the same results?

Having a hard time understanding the difference.

Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As its name says, [`RepeatedKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RepeatedKFold.html) is a repeated [`KFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html).
It executes it `n_repeats` times. When `n_repeats=1`, the former performs exactly as the latter when `shuffle=True`.
They do not return the same splits because `random_state=None` by default, that is, you did not specify it.
Therefore, they use different seeds to (pseudo-)randomly shuffle data.

When they have the same `random_state` and are repeated once, then both lead the same splits. For a deeper understanding try the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, RepeatedKFold
                     
data = pd.DataFrame([['red', 'strawberry'], # color, fruit
                  ['red', 'strawberry'], 
                  ['red', 'strawberry'],
                  ['red', 'strawberry'],
                  ['red', 'strawberry'],
                  ['yellow', 'banana'],
                  ['yellow', 'banana'],
                  ['yellow', 'banana'],
                  ['yellow', 'banana'],
                  ['yellow', 'banana']])

X = data[0]

# KFold
for train_index, test_index in KFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True, random_state=1).split(X):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)

# RepeatedKFold
for train_index, test_index in RepeatedKFold(n_splits=2, n_repeats=1, random_state=1).split(X):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
```

You should obtain the following:

```
TRAIN: [1 3 5 7 8] TEST: [0 2 4 6 9]
TRAIN: [0 2 4 6 9] TEST: [1 3 5 7 8]

TRAIN: [1 3 5 7 8] TEST: [0 2 4 6 9]
TRAIN: [0 2 4 6 9] TEST: [1 3 5 7 8]
```